# Doctrine's getResult() never returns and doesn't throw any errors or exceptions

Tags: doctrine-orm

I have two queries which I execute one after the other. They are extremely similar, yet the first one works and not the second one. Indeed, the second one never returns, nor does it throw any error or exception. Here is the relevant code:

```
$deleteChercheurProjetsQuery = $em->createQuery("DELETE FROM Entities\\ChercheurProjetRech P WHERE P.ProjetRechercheID IN (:existingProjetRechercheIds)")
    ->setParameter('existingProjetRechercheIds', $existingProjetRechercheIds, \Doctrine\DBAL\Connection::PARAM_INT_ARRAY);

$deleteProjetsQuery = $em->createQuery("DELETE FROM Entities\\ProjetRecherche P WHERE P.ID IN (:existingProjetRechercheIds)")
    ->setParameter('existingProjetRechercheIds', $existingProjetRechercheIds, \Doctrine\DBAL\Connection::PARAM_INT_ARRAY);

error_log("This message is logged");
$deleteChercheurProjetsQuery->getResult();
error_log("This message is also logged");
$deleteProjetsQuery->getResult();
error_log("This message is NOT logged");
```

How can I find out what the problem is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the problem was elsewhere. I wrapped the problematic line in a `try` block and found out that php was running out of memory at that point.